# Elementor Plugin on Wordpress keeps loading and I get a console error /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500

Tags: wordpress, elementor

how are you?

My website was working well and now I'm unable to create or edit pages using elementor because the 'loading' keeps spinning and nothing happens.

I see a console error where I get `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500`

How can I fix this? I don't know what caused it.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

there are many reason for this. But the common one is WP memory limit issue.

To handle this, first you need to edit the wp-config.php file on your WordPress site. It is located in your WordPress site’s root folder, and you will need to use an FTP client or file manager in your web hosting control panel.

Next, you need to paste this code in wp-config.php file just before the line that says ‘That’s all, stop editing! Happy blogging.’

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
```

This code tells WordPress to increase the PHP memory limit to 256MB.

Once you are done, you need to save your changes and upload your wp-config.php file back to your server.

Comment: You also can use higher limit like 512M, 1G, or 4G, but it is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, I just disabled plugins one by one and I found the problem!
**one of my plugins caused this problem.**

Comment: How did you figure this out ?

Comment: What plugin did you find that caused this problem?

Comment: The answer is broad and unspecific.